# Dotnet Core Web API Versioning

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I constructed my first dotnet core web api today and found something I can't resolve. I'm hoping someone can see what I'm doing wrong.

Here's code that works as expected.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class HelpController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

However, when I try to apply versioning, I get nothing.

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class HelpController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "hello world";
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddApiVersioning(option =>
    {
       option.ReportApiVersions = true;
       option.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
       option.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    });
}
```

The code compiles as expected, but I get nothing. I think the url should be `localhost://.../api/1/help`, but that doesn't work. It sends back a 404. I've tried "1," "1.0," "1_0," and "10." Nothing works.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you add v in front of version number, and see it makes any different? 
`[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there is a change in the latest 1.1 version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` package.

Try adding `app.UseApiVersioning();` in the `Configure` method.

**UPDATE:**
In version 1.2.0 the need for `app.UseApiVersioning();` is removed.